# PowerShell script to extract odd or even numbered lines inside a text file

Tags: powershell, file, text

I am trying to extract data present inside a text file but i am getting error. as i need to extract data from multiple text files, i am using a for-each loop and trying to get content from it.

Script i am trying to execute:

```
 $txtFiles = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\Vinay.Prasanth\Desktop\test\'
 foreach ($File in $txtFiles) {
     "Processing {0}" -f $File.fullname
     $Data = get-content $File.fullname
     "I Read {0} lines." -f $Data.Count
     $Content = Get-Content $File
    
For($i = 0; $i -lt $Content.Length; $i += 4 )
{
    $Content[$i]
}

 }
```

Text inside a text file

#TYPE Selected.System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry
"EntryType","TimeGenerated","Source","EventID","Category","Message"
"Information","3/1/2022 10:15:01 AM","Ems Event Detection Windows Service","0","(0)","Timestamp: 3/1/2022 10:15:01 AM
Message: Stopped polling at 48
Category: EventDetectionWindowsService
Priority: 0
EventId: 0
Severity: Information
Title:
"

Actual Output:

```
Processing C:\Users\Vinay.Prasanth\Desktop\test\SSPLog_20220301_101502AM - Copy
I Read 1227991 lines.
Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\SSPLog_20220301_101502AM - Copy' because it does not exist.
At line:6 char:17
+      $Content = Get-Content $File
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\WINDOWS\syst...101502AM - Copy:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

Expected output:

Category: EventDetectionWindowsService

Could you please help me where i am doing wrong and steps that would get me to the desired output.

Comment: Why would you use $file.fullname everywhere except get-content? Probably the issue

Comment: Have you considered using `Import-Csv` or `ConvertFrom-Csv` to parse your data? They'll take care of handling the multi-line string field correctly so you don't need to worry about grabbing the correct number of trailing new lines.